# Query to find records that were active within a range of dates

Tags: sql

I have a database table containing the start and expire date of employee certifications.  I need to query the table to get employees who were certified during a date range.

Example table:

```
  EmpID  |   FromDate  |  ExpireDate
---------+-------------+--------------
    1    |   2/1/2011  |    3/1/2015
    2    |  10/1/2010  |    2/1/2013
    3    |   3/1/2013  |   5/30/2013
    4    |  11/1/2000  |    3/1/2012
    5    |   5/6/2013  |   5/30/2017
```

If a user wants to find employees that were certified between 5/1/2013 and 5/30/2013 they should get back employee ids 1, 3, and 5.  Note that employee id 5 was certified during the date range though the FromDate is after the start date of the query (5/1/2013).

Hope that makes sense.  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your dates are really stored as dates, the following should work:

```
select t.*
from t
where FromDate <= '5/30/2013' and
      EndDate >= '5/1/2013';
```

The logic is that `FromDate` is less than the end of the period and `EndDate` is after the beginning.  That will get any overlap at all with the period.

Comment: you forgot to put "AND" to your query :)

Comment: I tested the 3 answers given and this is the only one that seems to be giving the correct results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The query will be:

```
declare @FromDate datetime
declare @ToDate datetime

set @FromDate = '1-May-2013'
set @ToDate = '30-May-2013'

select * from emp
where (@FromDate <= FromDate And @ToDate > FromDate And @ToDate < ExpireDate)   
    Or (@FromDate >= FromDate And  @ToDate between FromDate and ExpireDate)
```

Here both the conditions are separately mentioned and added using or operator. It will help you to write down your query in more logical manner.

Answer (score 0):

you have to select

```
SELECT EmpId FROM tableName  WHERE FromDate <= endDateRange AND
ExpireDate>=startDateRange
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there are 3 scenarios of this query.

Considering 5/1/2013 as st_dt
and 5/30/2013 as end_dt

```
Select EmpID from tablename WHERE
(st_dt > FromDate AND end_dt < ExpireDate) OR
(st_dt > FromDate AND end_dt > ExpireDate) OR
(st_dt < FromDate AND end_dt < ExpireDate);
```

Make certain changes in this query like table name, etc. You will get your answer for sure.

Comment: In your query EmpID 4 will also come since it qualifies your last condition `(st_dt < FromDate AND end_dt < ExpireDate)`.

Comment: Ohh.. That's right. Thanks for your comment Roopesh.

Comment: This will bring every record on the database